# when i run the code "php artisan migrate --seed" that's not work completely

Tags: php, laravel

when i run this code "php artisan migrate --seed" qppeaer one error like

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'naryn.modules' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `modules` where `module` = admin/backup_v2 limit 1)

Comment: Could you please provide us with a screenshot to see migrations directory and other screen from terminal to know which file crashed ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your database, stacktrace, and code this will be hard to answer.

But is this the first time that you ran the migration? If not, it's possible that you dropped the tables (the modules table specifically), but you did not drop the migration table. If the modules migration record still exists it will not run the migration and will not cause an error, hence going to the seeder even when there's no table migrated.

I would suggest if your still on the development phase and you can still drop the tables, just drop the schema and create it again to make sure it's a clean migration.